# C# - Stop ServiceProcess wrapper after java process is stopped

Tags: java, c#, batch-file, service

I'm building a c sharp serviceProcess that will start a  Batch file (the batch file will start a java application). 
If i stop the service it kills the java process. Stopping the java process can take up to 2 minutes. The service has to wait for the java application to stop, so i made a sleep.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( );
```

Is it possible to check if the "java" process is closed and after that stop the ServiceProcess.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the process using the [Process-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx). It allows you to get several information about a specific process. When you start the java.exe directly (using `Process.Start`) you already have the `Process`-instance.

When using a batch-file, you need to find the process, which is not a problem at all. You can find a process using [Process.GetProcessesByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx), but you'd find all all java-processes running on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
        Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Java");
        if (proc.Count() != 0)
        {
            //Process Alive
            Process prod = proc[0];
            prod.Kill();
            prod.WaitForExit();
        }
        else
        {
            //Process Dead
        }
```

A better option would be to use the process ID(if you know it)

Warning: This will kill the first java process it finds, you need to check which one you need to kill...